# How to launch msconfig.exe from Java?

Tags: java, command-line, command, execute

Ok, so I've been looking around for a while, and I can't figure out what's wrong with my program. I'm trying to make a cmd.exe like program. One command is supposed to launch msconfig.exe, located in C:/Windows/System32. But it gives me a java.io.IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/Windows/System32/msconfig.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here's my code:

```
    public static void msconfig() {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/msconfig.exe");
        InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
        InputStream err = process.getErrorStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Console.printToConsole("Could not launch msconfig.exe");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Console.printToConsole("Successfuly launched msconfig.exe");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
 So I exported the application with Eclipse and now it works fine! Thank you everybody who tried to help me :)

Comment: First up, I don't think you've understood how 'finally' works. Finally is a statement used to indicate something that should *always* be done, regardless of whether the try block completed successfully or threw an Exception. Your print statement from finally should be the last statement in try.

Comment: Strange. It works for me. Can it be to do with local admin privileges, I wonder? And most obvious thing to check, of course, if the file is there. :-)

Comment: @maksimov I did, I've used it a lot, and I know the file exists because
1) I've seen it in the directory
2) You can copy and paste the directory into Windows Explorer and the application launches.

Comment: @Ina Sorry about that, I haven't used the finally block before. I was just experimenting with it, and I've only been coding for about 9 months.

Comment: @whowantsakookie no need to apologise, this is how we learn! Good luck

Comment: If you find your own answer, post it as answer, and mark it as accepted answer. So people, searching with a similar problem, can find your thread and see it is solved, and what the solution is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path on a Windows computer uses backslashes as a separator. Use:

```
Process process = rt.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\msconfig.exe");
```

Just for the sake of completeness, the backslashes need to be doubled because they are the escape character and need to be escaped themselves.

Comment: Really? Somehow the code works unchanged for me on Windows 7 and Java 6.

Comment: @whowantsakookie That's not a reason to downvote me. You didn't say you tried that.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I didn't down vote you. I don't have enough rep to do that yet.

Comment: @whowantsakookie Sorry my fault. I wonder why the downvote was then. Whoever did it, please care to explain.

Comment: As far as I know, that is **not** true if you use the path in the class `File` for example. There is a reason the class `File` has a static `File.separator` variable to use in the path Strings.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I didn't care to downvote you, but your answer doesn't help as it works with forward slashes just as well as with double back-slashes.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester It could just be that windows also accepts forward slash as a path separator, but it does work to use forward slashes to access files on windows (I have used it before, and just tested again).

Answer (score 1):

You are using "wrong" backslashes. windows path work with \

try the path c:\windows\system32\msconfig.exe

Comment: Windows accepts slashes, and they're more easy to type. For relative paths (without drive letters like "C:" in front), you gain portability, for example if you load "./icon.gif".